# Getting params from url React

Tags: reactjs, parameters, router

Hy
i am trying to get row id from url. I am openning a model on every row in table shown at frontend. and every row is passing its index id to url through Link. But when i am trying to get this id in function which is called through onClick (on the same button which is opening model). It is then giving me id of previously clicked row.
Like if i am clicking row 0 it will give undefined and when i click row 1 it will give row 0 and so on.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXM0e.png)

Comment: Please put your working code on codesandbox

Comment: What is the `index` in `getData`? From my understanding of your question is If `index` is the row id, then you can use that directly. No need for changing URL.
Please provide the code if it is in another case. Then we can take a better look at it.

Comment: Please show how have you defined your routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by removing link from the button and passing parameter directly to getData function.
Because the issue was that onClick function was getting fired before React router changes the url.
I changed the onClick function to this onClick={() => this.getData(index)}